# How to pass parameter through sectionHyperlink in Pie chart?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I am using JR server 4.5 and Ireport 4.5 and I need help in passing a parameter from one parent pieChart to child report through sectionHyperlink.

I gone through several posts but couldn't get a solution which really worked.
So please help me.

Thanks

Comment: the answer will mainly depend on where you provide these reports. I.E. Are you using JasperReports Server to host your reports or a custom application?

Comment: Yes, I am using JasperReport Server to host all reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to define a hyperlink to another report in JasperReports Server you'd need to do the following

- open the report in iReport
- in the report designer right click on the chart and select *Chart Data* > *Details* > *Section Hyperlink*
- There configure:

  - Hyperlink Target: as prefered
  - Hyperlink Type: `Report Execution`
  - Link parameters: Click add

    - name: `_report`, class: (default), value: `path/to/report` (URI, e.g. `/reports/samples/Employees`). Click *Ok*.
    - add other parameters, name needs to be the name as used in the referred report, value is any expression to define the parameter's value for the drill down
  - Tooltip: set if desired.
- click *Close*.
- Save your report and deploy to JasperReports Server.

The report you are referring to needs to be accessible for the user - the user needs to have read permission, the URI is the full path from repository root.

If you look at the sample reports that come with JasperReports you'll find other examples for drill down reports.